# May I know how retrofit support 304 Not Modifield?

Tags: android, http, client, retrofit

Anyone know how retrofit support 304 Not Modifield?
Because right now retrofit will throw error.
I am using etag to check whether the json should update or not.

```
@GET("/imageslist.json") Response fetch(@Header("If-None-Match") String etag);
```

That is how i handle right now

```
ImageService service = restAdapter.create(ImageService.class);
Response response = null;
try {
    response = service.fetch("\"vENxxg\"");
} catch (RetrofitError e) {
    if (e.getResponse().getStatus() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
        //Nothing to update
        response = e.getResponse();
    } else {
        Log.e("Retrofit", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You might be able to get this by wiring up OkHttp with its built-in response cache. It'll remember etags and do conditional caching for automatically.

Comment: Hi @JesseWilson , I have implement the retrofit ErrorHandler, and throw some CustomErrorException. that work well...thanks to retrofit to create a flexible libraby